Error: prettier.resolveConfig is not a function (ESLint/Prettier Rule)
I'm encountering an error during linting in my React project:
Error: prettier.resolveConfig is not a function
Occurred while linting `path`
Rule: "prettier/prettier"

Those dependencies are used:
        "@emotion/react": "^11.11.0",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
        "@formatjs/cli": "^5.1.13",
        "@ladle/react": "^2.12.3",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
        "@tippyjs/react": "^4.2.6",
        "@types/async": "^3.2.20",
        "@types/howler": "^2.2.7",
        "@types/node": "^18.16.15",
        "@types/pako": "^2.0.0",
        "@types/react": "^18.2.7",
        "@types/ws": "^8.5.4",
        "dexie": "^3.2.3",
        "framer-motion": "^11.2.10",
        "howler": "^2.2.3",
        "jsdom": "^20.0.3",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "logrocket": "^3.0.1",
        "pako": "^2.1.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.23",
        "prettier": "^2.8.8",
        "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.1.13",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "screenfull": "^6.0.2",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
        "tailwindcss-debug-screens": "^2.2.1",
        "typescript": "^4.9.5",
        "xo": "^0.58.0",

The .xo-config.json configuration file used with xo (ESLint wrapper):
{
    "space": 4,
    "prettier": true,
    "ignores": ["capacitor.config.ts", "android/**", "ios/**", "vite.config.ts", "node_modules", "dist", "build"],
    "rules": {
        "import/extensions": 0,
        "no-warning-comments": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-definitions": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return": 0,
        "unicorn/prefer-switch": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/ban-types": 0,
        "unicorn/no-array-reduce": 0,
        "n/file-extension-in-import": 0,
        "unicorn/filename-case": 0,
        "import/no-unassigned-import": 0,
        "unicorn/prefer-module": 0,

        "unicorn/prevent-abbreviations": [
            "error",
            {
                "replacements": {
                    "param": false,
                    "params": false,
                    "props": false,
                    "args": false,
                    "e": false,
                    "ref": false,
                    "db": false,
                    "env": false,
                    "endOfLine": false
                }
            }
        ],

        "no-restricted-imports": [
            "error",
            {
                "paths": [
                    {
                        "name": "lodash",
                        "importNames": ["default"],
                        "message": "Use named imports"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

The .prettierrc  configuration file used by Prettier:
{
    "printWidth": 120,
    "trailingComma": "all",
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "endOfLine": "auto"
}

How can I resolve it to continue using Prettier formatting with `xo`?
Are there any compatibility issues between Prettier ^2.8.8 and the "prettier/prettier" rule?

In my case, upgrading to prettier v3 helped with eslint v9.
